# How To print a result of ActionResult if it is Done

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

How to print a result after calling ActionResult?

For example, here is my call from a view:

```
 <a title="Add To Read Later" 
    target="_blank" 
    href="@(Url.Action("Insert", "ReadLater",new {Book_id=Model.Book.Book_id }))">
      <small class="fa fa-2x fa-plus"></small>
 </a>
```

And here is my `ReadLaterController` method:

```
public ActionResult Insert(int? Book_id)
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var x = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var result = db.Books.Where(p => p.Book_id == Book_id).Single();
        if(result.Book_id == Book_id)
        {
            var IsExists = db.ReadLaters.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Book_Id == result.Book_id && t.User_Id==x);
            if (IsExists == null)
            {
                ReadLater ReadL = new ReadLater()
                {
                    Book_Id = result.Book_id,
                    User_Id = x.ToString()
                };
                db.ReadLaters.Add(ReadL);
                int state = db.SaveChanges();
                if (state == 1)
                {

                    return new JavaScriptResult { Script = "alert('Successfully Added');" };
                }
            }
            else
            {

                 return new JavaScriptResult { Script = "alert('You Added This book Before');" };

            }
        }
    }

    return new JavaScriptResult { Script = "alert('Not Added');" };
}
```

As you see, if the content was added to database, I want to show an alert in the same page from which I called the controller, saying: if the data added or not added or already added depend on the method result ....

Right now it works by going to the method URL and printing the result there without JavaScript effects, just as text:

> http://localhost:49119/ReadLater/Insert?Book_id=19

And the result in that URL is:

> alert('You Added This book Before');

Comment: You could try calling the action with AJAX and passing the Book_id int that way.. then on success you can alert the appropriate alert. This doesn't answer your question directly but might be a clean alternative.

Comment: If you want to stay on the same page then you must use ajax

Comment: How to do that @StephenMuecke  Cause actually I have not experience with Ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an AJAX example you could use. I put it as a button.. It could be whatever you want though.

Html

```
    <button data-id="@Model.Book.Book_id" class="insertButton fa fa-2x fa-plus">Add to Read Later</button>
```

Ajax

```
            $('.insertButton').click(function () {

                var myId = $(this).data('id');

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: '@Url.Action("Insert","ReadLater")?Book_id=' + myId,
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert(response);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert("Failure");
                    }
                });
            });
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Insert(int? Book_id)
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var x = User.Identity.GetUserId();
                var result = db.Books.Where(p => p.Book_id == Book_id).Single();
                if (result.Book_id == Book_id)
                {
                    var IsExists = db.ReadLaters.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Book_Id == result.Book_id && t.User_Id == x);
                    if (IsExists == null)
                    {
                        ReadLater ReadL = new ReadLater()
                        {
                            Book_Id = result.Book_id,
                            User_Id = x.ToString()
                        };
                        db.ReadLaters.Add(ReadL);
                        int state = db.SaveChanges();
                        if (state == 1)
                        {

                            return Content("Successfully Added");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        return Content("You Added This book Before");

                    }
                }
            }

            return Content("Not Added");
        }
```

Comment: `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` is pointless and the `Book_id` should be added as a `data-` attribute and access using `var myId = $(this).data('id');`.

Comment: I agree with that.. forgot to strip out that contentType also i'll update the answer to use a data- attribute instead of the ID.

Comment: @mwwallace8 , after last edit you make , the method is not receiving the data (book_id)

Comment: Hmm. It works for me still... I notice you wrote book_id and not Book_id. Maybe it's a case-sensitivity issue? My edit was 2 lines of the script and also edited the button attributes. Make sure you have both or it won't work.

Comment: Yes your are right I missed the data-id , thanks a lot